# An inequality question with three unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x^2+mx+2n-1>0$

**If the solution set of the inequality is $R-(5)$. What is the sum of $m+n$?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:Write your inequality in the form $$\left(x+\frac{m}{2}\right)^2+2n-1-\frac{m^2}{4}>0$$

Comment: I wrote it in that form but I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: should your inequality be fulfilled for all real $x$?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Then it must be $$2n-1-\frac{m^2}{4}=0$$ and $$\left(x+\frac{m}{2}\right)^2\neq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:$$\left(x+\frac{m}{2}\right)^2+2n-1-\frac{m^2}{4}>0$$ after that what i could think of is that x=5 is the point where $$\left(x+\frac{m}{2}\right)^2$$  turns zero and $$2n-1-\frac{m^2}{4}$$  turns zero simultaneously..